# Law of large number with subset of the variables

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

Let $(X_i, Y_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be iid continuous random vectors with continuous joint density, where $X_1$ have support $\mathcal{X}$. Let $B_n\subset \mathcal{X}\subset\mathbb{R}$ be decreasing subsets (open intervals) such that $\cap B_n= x_0\in\mathcal{X}$.

Let $S = \{i\leq n: X_i\in B_n\}$.
I want to show that
$$
\frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{i\in S}Y_i \overset{P}{\to} \mathbb{E}[Y_1\mid X_1=x_0], \,\,as\,\,n\to\infty. 
$$
I assume that the necessary condition for this convergence is $|S|\to\infty$ or that $nP(X_i\in B_n)\to\infty$. Is it sufficient? Is there some theory that describes this?

Comment: What does $\{i \leq n : X_i \in B_n\}$ mean if $X_i$'s are random variables?

Comment: @balddraz  It is a size of a (random) set defined as subset of $\{1, \dots, n\}$. It is the number of times that $X_i$ fell into $B_n$.

Comment: Whether $X_i \in B_n$ or not has a probability; it is not a true or false proposition. So I don't understand what the set $\{i \leq n : X_i \in B_n\}$ is supposed to be. Is it a random set?

Comment: @mihaild Yes, thanks, I corrected it. Balddraz yes, it is a random set